# Sorted Linked list in c just stops

Tags: c

I tried to create a self-sorting linked list in C, but after I run the create_a_node function, I am prompted twice for a number to add, then the program just stops, it doesn't seem to end or have a segmentation fault, it just stops and I can't figure out why, what am I doing wrong

```
node* create_a_node(int input){
    node *head = NULL;
    node *curptr = NULL;
    node *newptr = NULL;
    node *prvptr;

int NTA;

printf("please enter a number to add: ");
scanf("%i",&NTA);

while(NTA != -1){

    newptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // create a new node
    newptr->data = NTA;
    newptr->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL){
        head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->next = newptr;

    }
    else{ // if a head exists
        curptr = head;

        while(curptr->next!= NULL){ 
                prvptr = curptr;
                curptr = curptr->next;
                if(curptr->data > NTA){
                    prvptr->next = newptr;
                    newptr->next = curptr;
                }
                else{
                    if(curptr->next == NULL){
                        curptr->next = newptr;
                    }
                    else{
                        curptr = curptr->next;
                        }

                }

        }

    }
    printf("please enter a number to add: ");
    scanf("%i",&NTA);

}
return head;
}
```

Comment: If `head` is `NULL`, then shouldn't the newly created node be the head? You are creating a new node that has no valid `data`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your inner while() loop - `while(curptr->next!=NULL)`.  Namely, it never breaks! It's an infinite loop. To get your code working, you should try this:

```
    while(curptr->next!= NULL) {
        prvptr = curptr;
        curptr = curptr->next;
        if(curptr->data > NTA) {
            prvptr->next = newptr;
            newptr->next = curptr;
            break;
        }
        else if(curptr->next == NULL){
            curptr->next = newptr;
            break;
        }
    }
```

A few notes:

- I added two `break` statements.  Right now the loop will continue until `curptr->next` is null, but you insert your node in the first `if()` statement.  To continue the loop after that would result in double insertion, which is likely NOT what you are wanting.
- You are currently executing `curptr = curptr->next;` at the start of the while() loop, and then you execute it *again* in the nestled `else` block - that would be jumping over two list items, which again is likely NOT what you are wanting.
- I strongly suggest you take some time to write out the logic of your program on paper first.  Your `head` pointer will never have associated data, which is uncommon in linked lists.  You don't handle a situation where the `while(curptr->next!=NULL)` loop exists without having made an insertion (which is obviously the intent of the loop), the `input` argument has no usage in the function, et cetera.

Linked lists can be tough to learn, so take it slow.  Right now it's difficult to identify what exactly you're intending each piece of the code to do, and you don't have much error handling.  That makes it difficult to "fix" your code, but the code block above should get the code *running* - from there on out you'll need to address the *logic* issues in your code.